# Smart Home CameraStream with webrtc

Tags: session, webrtc, google-home

I want to ask one problem ,when Smart Home CameraStream with webrtc,in signaling request ,
Header:

Authentication: Bearer 
Content-Type: application/json

POST body:

// When camera offer SDP is provided in the execution response, Google provides an answer SDP.

```
{
  "action": "answer",
  "deviceId": "123",
  "sdp": "o=- 4611731400430051336 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1..."
}
```

// When camera offer SDP is not provided in execution response, Google generates and provides an offer SDP.

```
{
  "action": "offer",
  "deviceId": "123",
  "sdp": "o=- 4611731400430051336 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1..."
}
```

// Close the current stream session.

```
{
  "action": "end"
  "deviceId": "123"
}
```

how can I know the difference between the session, it is only action,deviceId, and SDP, can not know what session.